# Determining whether a C struct is packed or not

Tags: gcc, gdb, gdb-python, pahole

I'm extracting C struct layout from and executable using gdb-python.

I manage to get all the fields, offsets, types & sizes.

Still, when trying to re-generate the struct's code, I do not have any indication for whether it was marked with GCC's `attribute((__packed__))`.

Is there any way to get this information from the executable? (preferably using gdb-python, but any other way will do too)

Comment: "when trying to re-generate the struct's code" -- *why* would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have the same struct in 2 binaries (2 versions of the same binary). I want to detect any changes made to the struct between the 2 versions. Based on those changes, I generate a "copy" function for the fields that were left unchanged. I have to modify the name of the struct as "_old" (and recursively all the structs within it). I have other ways to do it, but I would like to use the same infrastructure I'm using to detect the changes (gdb-python).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get this information from the executable?

No, but you should be able to deduce this with a simple heuristic:

- if `sizeof(struct foo)` is greater than the sum of its member field sizes, the struct is not packed.
- if `sizeof(struct foo)` is equal to the sum of its member field sizes, the struct is *either* packed, *or* its members are naturally aligned with no holes, and packing doesn't matter for it.

Comment: gdb-python alreday gives me the size of each field after packing, so this is not an option.

Comment: I can compare the field sizes in gdb-python to those I can find using static code analysis of some kind (ctypesgen, ctypeslib...), but I would prefer to avoid it.